# full node bitcoin, l have a 32 bit pc,can I run a node with an SSD?

Tags: bitcoin-core

full node bitcoin
I have a 32-bit Windows 7 PC, can I run a node with an SSD?

Comment: You mean to save the node data to external SSD?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: If you have both HDD and SSD, the blocksdir parameter should help: let SSD handle the intensive random I/O, while HDD would handle the gigantic blockchain storage.

Comment: intel,T2050 ,1.60 GHz   RAM 3,00 GB   Windows 7    OS 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Most likely. This [page](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#windows-7) has instructions on how to download and run bitcoin core. You can checkout the Cost and Warnings section to see if your machine is capable.

If you need to store the blockchain on an external ssd, you need to edit the bitcoin.conf file to point the `datadir` at your drives location. Here's more information on [bitcoin.conf](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/bitcoin-conf.md).

Answer (score 0):

You might have to compile from source if no 32 bit nodes are available for download.